# ggplot2 in R not generating 1000+ plots in pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting 1500 plots into a pdf using ggplot2 in R. But my output pdf has only 1000 plots/pages. How do we print all 1500 in pdf?

Code below for your reference:

```
plots_list = list()
for(i in 1:1500){
  p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_line(aes(y = hp)) 
  plots_list[[i]] = p
}

pdf("final_plots.pdf")
plots_list
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `max.print` option to a higher number:

```
options(max.print = 1500)
```

Or iterate over your `plots_list`:

```
pdf("final_plots.pdf")
for (i in 1:length(plots_list)) {
  print(plots_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```